# Getting Undefined variable: PHP_SELF

Tags: php

This an app code I downloaded from a site but it shows in error log 
Getting Undefined variable: PHP_SELF on line 150, in index.php, now line 150 is

```
<form name=test action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="GET">
```

This is the full code of the form

```
<form name=test action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="GET">
    <table border=0 align=center>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="name" onclick="this.value=''" value="<?php echo $firstName ?>" name=p1>
                </td>
                <td style="background-image: url(images/heart.png); width: 133px; height: 119px; align: center;">
                    <div id=targetDiv align=center valign="top" style="font-size: 36px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                        <?php 
                            echo $result;
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="name" onclick="this.value=''" value="<?php echo $secondName ?>" name=p2>
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its supposed to be an index in the `$_SERVER` variable:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" ...>
```

Of course unless you defined it:

```
$PHP_SELF = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

Alternatively, you could also omit it since your intent is to submit the form in the current page:

```
<form action=""
```

Comment: Thanks alot , solved it 
Thanks for the quick response

If I omit it, the form does not loads.

it solved when I defined $_SERVER

Comment: @Danyal sure, glad this shed some light

Answer (score 2):

I think your looking for the server variable:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
```

Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Thank You so much , The reference is appreciated :)